# What is the difference between a page load and window.location.assign()

Tags: javascript, html, browser, reload, difference

When I ran this html code(name: Test.html):

```
    <body>
      <a id="button" href="Test.html#no">Reload</a><br>
      <!-- some code here -->
      <a name='no'></a>Messi
      <script>
        let a = 0;
        let reloadbtn = document.querySelector('#button');
        reloadbtn.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
          console.log(window.location.href);
        })
      </script>
    </body>
```

via a page load/reload, and I click the Reload link, I get **'path/to/Test.html#no' printed at the console.**
However, if I refresh the page with `window.location.assign('Test.html')`, and click the Reload link on the page, I get **'path/to/Test.html'** printed at the console.

It seems the browser load/reload makes links assigns the `window.location.href` property correctly when clicked, but the `window.location.assign()` dosen't.

I would like to know the difference between a browser load and window.location.assign()?; How does JavaScript behave with these respectively? Can a browser load/reload be simulated accurately with JavaScript?

**Edit:**
When I change my script code to this:

```
 <body>
      <a id="button" href="Test.html#no">Reload</a><br>
      <!-- some code here -->
      <a name='no'></a>Messi
      <script>
        let a = 0;
        let reloadbtn = document.querySelector('#button');
        reloadbtn.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
          console.log(window.location.href);
        setTimeout(()=>(console.log(window.location.href)), 1000);
      })
      </script>
   </body>
```

and refresh the page with `window.location.assign('Test.html')`, and click the Reload link, I get ***'path/to/Test.html'*** and ***'path/to/Test.html#no'*** printed at the console; which seems to me that `window.location.assign()` makes links assign the `window.location.href` property after the click handler executes.

Tested on Firefox (v72.0.2) and Chrome (v91.0.4472.106)

Comment: I learned that window.location.reload() works like a browser reload.

Comment: I believe you'd have to use `window.location.assign('Test.html#no')` in order to get the same behavior as your link.